# How to show empty date picker in Material UI- REACT?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

#### CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
     <DatePicker
      fullWidth
      value={dob}
      label="Date of Birth"
      format="dd / MM / yyyy"
      margin="normal"
      maxDate={new Date()}
      InputProps={{ className: css.datepicker }}
      ></DatePicker>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

#### CSS Code

```
.datepicker {
  margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 20px 15px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $lightGrey;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

#### Current Behaviour when empty

[image: Current Implementation]

#### Expected Behaviour when empty

[image: Expected Behaviour]

Is it possible to style the Material UI date picker in my expected way of look as the image attached?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Just provide the initial value of date as null (in your state) then it will work the way you expected.
- Also you can use [emptyLabel](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker) prop to provide custom placeholder when date is null

[see demo in codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-date-picker-datepicker-issue-fix-tn36r?file=/src/App.jsx)

**code**

```js
function App() {
  const [dob, setDob] = useState(null); //<--- pass initial value as null
  const handleDateChange = date => {
    setDob(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        fullWidth
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        value={dob}
        label="Date of Birth"
        format="dd / MM / yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        maxDate={new Date()}
        emptyLabel="custom label" //<--- custom placeholder when date is null
        //  InputProps={{ className: css.datepicker }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

**Edit**: answering follow-up qns based on comment.

1. **Remove the floating label when date is null** - provide value to label when `dob` has a value

```js
label={dob && "Date of Birth"}
```

2. **Apply styles for Empty label** - Use `makeStyles` and `InputProps`

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  datepicker: {
    margin: "2px 0px 2px 0px",
    height: "60px",
    // width: 'fit-content',
    padding: "20px 15px 10px",
    borderBottom: "2px solid blue",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    color: "#2c2c2c",
    width: 300,
    fontWeight: 600
  }
}));

function App() {
  const [dob, setDob] = useState(null); //<--- pass initial value as null
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleDateChange = date => {
    setDob(date);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        fullWidth
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        value={dob}
        label={dob && "Date of Birth"}
        format="dd / MM / yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        maxDate={new Date()}
        emptyLabel="custom label" //<--- custom placeholder when date is null
        InputProps={{ className: !dob ? classes.datepicker : null }} //<----apply style when no date selected
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

The codesandbox demo has been updated to reflect all the points above.

Comment: Is it possible to change the css of the empty label? and also is it possible to remove the floating label when date is null?

Comment: also please see if you can consider to upvote and accept the answer, thanks

Comment: Also is it possible to move the floating label to the inside of the textbox?

Comment: try giving `placeholder={"Date of Birth"}` ... i have updated the demo .. use same link and reload browser.

Answer (score 0):

This code will cause that MUI DatePicker will not display error when date value is null/undefined:

```js
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker
    value={birthDate != null ? dayjs(birthDate) : null}
    onChange={(newValue) => setBirthDate(newValue)}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```